# Hide menu options from Power BI report

Tags: .net, powerbi, blazor, powerbi-embedded

I have a Embed Power BI on my Asp .Net app, I use the JavaScript Api to embed the Power BI to my view.
In Power BI report we have 3 menu options (File, Home, View) and I want to remove/hide it can anyone tell me how I can remove/hide it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please add it to your question in a code block.  Also is Power BI Blazor?

Comment: @sunny kapare, What do you mean by three menu options ? do you mean by three pages in report and want to hide the pageNavigation pane ?

Comment: Can you reframe your question, in detailed, What is your required output, what you have tried and what issue you are facing.  some screenshots or code you implemented will be great.

Comment: Menu option means navigation menu.

Comment: I already tried to make pageNavigation pane to false but didn't work

Comment: @SunnyKapare, Refer to below answer, this is how we hide the Navigation Pane. If, you are still facing the issue, you need to provide some code snippets and reframe your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To Hide the Navigation Pane in your report,

1. Make the pageNavigation pane in settings to false.

```
const newSettings = {
 panes: {
     pageNavigation: {
         visible: false
     }
 }
};
```

2. Pass the updated settings either when embedding report (load time inside the embedConfig) or during run time using `updateSettings()` API.

References:

[Customize Setting Power BI Embedded](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/configure-report-settings#page-navigation-pane)

[Update Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/update-settings)